# Eigenspace with dimension equal to the domain

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to have a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ ($V$ a vector space over field $\mathbb{C}$, with dimension $n$) such that there is an eigenvalue lambda with an associated eigenspace which has a dimension $n$?

I am currently solving a problem and in the problem the Eigenspace is denoted as $W$ and the domain is denoted as $V$. Im wondering whether $W$ is a subset or a proper subset of $V$.

Comment: Look at the identity operator.

Comment: Thank you. So W is a subset of V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this for any $\lambda$. Fix $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ and consider the linear operator $T:V\to V$ which sends $x\mapsto \lambda x$. This operator has one eigenvalue, $\lambda$, whose corresponding eigenspace is $V$, which has dimension $n$.

The only way the eigenspace $W$ can have dimension $n$ is if it is all of $V$.